# How to get equal height columns when one column is split into two rows within Bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: two column equal height]

I need a **BOOTSTRAP 3** grid layout as above which is simply two columns and the first column is split into two rows.  **Col1** will hold some text, lists in each of the rows and **Col2** will hold an image.  The columns need to be equal height - I can’t achieve the equal heights.

I am using this css which works perfectly in other areas to achieve the equal heights of columns, but those columns have not been split into rows.

```
.row{
    overflow: hidden; 
}

[class*="col-md"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

I have tried using table-cells, and using max/min heights, but nothing is consistent.

**How can I achieve equal height columns when one of the columns is split into rows in Bootstrap 3 grid?**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/g7w26oec/3/)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

why not grid?

POC:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 200px;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.item2 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.item3 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">item 3</div>

</div>
```

smart layouts with `grid` are very easy.

more info: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/